# How to refactor to prevent component from losing its previous state (ReactJS)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lifecycle

I have the following function (in a FilterGroupSection component) which is called in the component's render method:

```
renderFilterGroups() {
    const {filterGroupsData, activeId} = this.state;
    let isActive;

    // get an array of FilterGroup objects from the filterGroup data
    const filterGroups = filterGroupsData.map((filterGroupData, index) => {
        const key = filterGroupData.key;
        const filters = filterGroupData.filters;

        if (key === activeId) {
            isActive = true;
        } else {
            isActive = false;
        }

        return (
            <FilterGroup
                key={key}
                id={filterGroupData.id}
                selectFilterGroup={() => {
                    this.selectFilterGroup(key);
                }}
                removeFilterGroup={e => {
                    this.removeFilterGroup(key, e);
                }}
                deselectFilter={(
                    filterGroupId,
                    filterIndex,
                    filterName
                ) => {
                    this.handleFilterDeselection(
                        filterGroupId,
                        filterIndex,
                        filterName
                    );
                }}
                isActive={isActive}
                filters={filters}
            />
        );

    });

    // add conjunction object between each filterGroup
    const filterGroupsConjunctions = [];
    for(const filterGroup of filterGroups) {
        if(filterGroupsConjunctions.length > 0){
            const conjunction = <Conjunction key={uuid()} />
            filterGroupsConjunctions.push(conjunction);
        }
        filterGroupsConjunctions.push(filterGroup);
    }

    return filterGroupsConjunctions;
}
```

The method returns an array of FilterGroup and Conjunction objects. The FilterGroup objects are created based on a data array in the state and a Conjunction object is added between multiple FilterGroups.

The Conjunction component has its own state which has a value property. Everytime a new FilterGroup is added, all the Conjunction objects are recreated as per the line (in the above function):

```
 const conjunction = <Conjunction key={uuid()} />
```

This means that the state of the Conjunction object is reset each time a new FilterGroup is added. I don't want the state of the Conjunction object to be reset. How can I stop this from happening?

My initial thoughts are that I should maybe move some of the functionality in the above method to a component lifecycle method.

Appreciate any advice.

Comment: Maybe you can assign the key to a value that doesn't change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this answer by storing the conjunction value in the same data array as the filter groups and then passing it as a prop to the conjunction component.

I also passed a handler function from the parent component (FilterGroupSection) to the child component (Conjunction) which is fired when the radio element in the conjunction component is changed. The function is as:

```
handleConjunctionChange(filterGroupId, conjunctionType) {
    let filterGroupsData = this.state.filterGroupsData; // all filter groups

    const index = filterGroupsData.findIndex(
        group => group.id === filterGroupId
    );

    filterGroupsData[index] = {
        ...filterGroupsData[index], // id, key and filter properties
        conjunctionType: conjunctionType// set/overwrite the property we interested in
    };

    this.setState({ filterGroupsData: filterGroupsData });
}
```

It saves the selected radio option value to the data array and in turn updates the state.